# How the X axis on a Linearregression is formated and processed?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to build a regression line based on date and closure price of a stock.
I know the regline doesn't allow to be calculated on date, so I transform the date to be a numerical value.

I have been able to format the data as it requires.
Here is my sample code :

```
import datetime as dt
import csv
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np

source = 'C:\\path'

#gets file
df = pd.read_csv(source+'\\ABBN.SW.csv')

#change string to datetime
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) 
#change datetime to numerical value
df['Date'] = df['Date'].map(dt.datetime.toordinal) 

#build X and Y axis
x = np.array(df['Date']).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.array(df['Close'])

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(x,y)

print(model.intercept_)
print(model.coef_)
```

---

```
print(x)
[[734623]
 [734625]
 [734626]
 ...
 [738272]
 [738273]
 [738274]]

print(y)
[16.54000092 16.61000061 16.5 28.82999992 28.88999939 ... 29.60000038]


intercept :  -1824.9528261991056 #complete off the charts, it should be around 18-20
coef :  [0.00250826]
```

The question here is : What I am missing on the X axis (date) to produce a correct intercept ?
It looks like the the coef is right tho.
See the example on excel (old data)
[image: examplexls]

References used :

1. https://realpython.com/linear-regression-in-python/
2. https://medium.com/python-data-analysis/linear-regression-on-time-series-data-like-stock-price-514a42d5ac8a
3. https://www.alpharithms.com/predicting-stock-prices-with-linear-regression-214618/

Comment: Time is - in your case - discontinuous due to business hours, weekends and holidays. That is why simple linear regression doesn't work. If you map the stock prices to a continous "trading time", you will be perfectly fine (lets say the x axis is the seconds a stock is traded since a defined beginning). I don't know if there is a function to do this automatically but I guess, ur not the first with this kind of problem, so chances are high =)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to apply min-max normalisation to your ordinal dates. In this manner you will get the desired "small" intercept out of the linear regression.

```
import datetime as dt
import csv
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
df['Date_ordinal'] = df["Date"].map(dt.datetime.toordinal)
df["Date_normalized"] = df["Date"].apply(lambda x: len(df["Date"]) * (x - df["Date"].min()) / (df["Date"].max() - df["Date"].min()))

print(df)

def apply_linear(df,label_dates):
    x = np.array(df[label_dates]).reshape(-1, 1)
    y = np.array(df['Close'])
    model = LinearRegression()
    model.fit(x,y)
    print("intercep = ",model.intercept_)
    print("coef = ",model.coef_[0])

print("Without normalization")
apply_linear(df,"Date_ordinal")

print("With normalization")
apply_linear(df,"Date_normalized")
```

And the results of my execution as follows, passing to it an invented representative data set for your purpose:

> ```
> PS C:\Users\ruben\PycharmProjects\stackOverFlowQnA> python .\main.py
>         Date  Close  Date_ordinal  Date_normalized
> 0 2022-04-01    111        738246         0.000000
> 1 2022-04-02    112        738247         0.818182
> 2 2022-04-03    120        738248         1.636364
> 3 2022-04-04    115        738249         2.454545
> 4 2022-04-05    105        738250         3.272727
> 5 2022-04-09     95        738254         6.545455
> 6 2022-04-10    100        738255         7.363636
> 7 2022-04-11    105        738256         8.181818
> 8 2022-04-12    112        738257         9.000000
>
> Without normalization
> intercep =  743632.8904761908
> coef =  -1.0071428571428576
>
> With normalization
> intercep =  113.70476190476191
> coef =  -1.2309523809523817
> ```

Comment: Notice that I've added a gap in the time series of dates simulating weekend and/or bank holiday